# Problem creating array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a javascript code below.

```
bgCustom = { 'items':[], 'items_num':3, 'element':'#bg_custom_thumbs', 'next': '#bg_custom_next_thumb', 'prev': '#bg_custom_prev_thumb', 'width':165 };
//populate array
bgCustom.items = [["images/backgrounds/bear-ears_thumb.jpg", "bear-ears.jpg", "Bear-Hair"], ["images/backgrounds/blue-swirls_thumb.jpg", "blue-swirls.jpg", "WaterSmoke"]];
```

ho do i create bgCustom.items array dynamic. means i want a array list

```
[['val1_1','val1_2','val1_3'],['val2_1','val2_2','val2_3']]
```

Can any body help me.

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamic'?

Comment: how do i creat this type of array 
[['val1_1','val1_2','val1_3'],['val2_1','val2_2','val2_3']]

Comment: I don't see what the problem is, everything you've done should work.

Comment: yes but right now bgCustom.items is static values i want dynamic values

Comment: Still not clear what you mean by saying static or dynamic. In that  array you can push values, remove values, change values... so what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There's no such thing as a static array in JavaScript like there is in C(++). All arrays you create are expandable at will and can be filled with any type you want - mixed types included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bgCustom = { 'items':[], 'items_num':3, 'element':'#bg_custom_thumbs', 'next': '#bg_custom_next_thumb', 'prev': '#bg_custom_prev_thumb', 'width':165 };

function PushToItems(a,b,c) {
    var ar = [a,b,c];
    bgCustom.items.push(ar);
}

PushToItems("images/backgrounds/bear-ears_thumb.jpg", "bear-ears.jpg", "Bear-Hair");
```

That should work for making it a little more dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

You can add arrays to the end of the array:

```
bgCustomer.items.push(['val1_1','val1_2','val1_3']);
bgCustomer.items.push(['val2_1','val2_2','val2_3']);
```

You can also assign arrays at specific indexes. The array will automatically expand if you use an index outside the current size:

```
bgCustomer.items[0] = ['val1_1','val1_2','val1_3'];
bgCustomer.items[1] = ['val2_1','val2_2','val2_3'];
```